# Invalid OAuth access token signature Error thrown

Tags: ios, facebook, ios7, access-token

I'm trying to access through my application some Facebook informations (friend's email, birthdays, events ...)
Below my code to extract these informations:

```
  - (void)getMe{

    NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://graph.facebook.com/%@?fields=birthday,email,first_name,last_name,username,gender,picture&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx|xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",_facebookAccount.username];
    NSString* webStringURL = [stringURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *meurl = [NSURL URLWithString: webStringURL];

    SLRequest *merequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook requestMethod:SLRequestMethodGET URL:meurl parameters:nil];

    merequest.account = _facebookAccount;
    NSLog(@"%@",_facebookAccount.username);
    [merequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        NSString *meDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        NSLog(@"%@", meDataString);

    }];

}
```

When i run my application on my iPhone, i got this error :

```
{"error":{"message":"Invalid OAuth access token signature.","type":"OAuthException","code":190}}
```

At the beginning i thought that the problem comes from the access token, but indeed, when i copy the content of webStringURL and paste it in the web browser, i get the informations that i want.

I've configured every thing well, that's why i have good results when i try t access  "https://graph.facebook.com/me".

Have you already seen this kind of problem ? and what's the solution for that.

Thanks

Comment: How did you generate the access token, through the SDK or through the Graph Explorer?  You should be generating it with the SDK

Comment: By the way, I don't see where you're setting your FB app ID or app secret.

Comment: I generate the access token like that : "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APPID&client_secret=APPSECRET&grant_type=client_credentials"

Comment: Facebook has an SDK that you should be using to do all of this.  Then all you'd have to do is either create a `FBSession` or use their prebuilt `FBLoginView` control. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/

Comment: But in this case i have not used the Facebook SDK, but the Social Framework instead.